# Access denied to mysql database as root in rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, root

I am running a rails app with mysql.
My computer shut down in an unorthodox way and now when I am trying to run `rails s` I get `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`

My database.yml file looks like :

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: or_deco__site_development
```

when Im trying to launch mysql server as root with `mysql start` I get this trace :

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61 "Connection refused")

when I try mysqld --user=mysql as why suggested on mysql website I get this trace:

2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.19-MariaDB) starting as process 1462 ...
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Warning] One can only use the --user switch if running as root

2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2017-06-07 18:10:54 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/gtid_slave_pos'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"mysql"."gtid_slave_pos"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_index_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"mysql"."innodb_index_stats"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_table_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"mysql"."innodb_table_stats"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/active_admin_comments'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."active_admin_comments"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/administrators'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."administrators"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/ar_internal_metadata'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."ar_internal_metadata"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/carousels'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."carousels"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/contacts'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."contacts"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/headers'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."headers"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/images'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."images"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/schema_migrations'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."schema_migrations"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 7fff7d53a300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/sections'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tablespace open failed for '"or_deco__site_development"."sections"', ignored.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"mysql"."innodb_table_stats"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 1.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 127a27000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_table_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"mysql"."innodb_index_stats"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 2.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 127a27000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'mysql/innodb_index_stats'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"or_deco__site_development"."images"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 27.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 127a27000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/images'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"or_deco__site_development"."carousels"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 13.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 127a27000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/carousels'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to find tablespace for table '"or_deco__site_development"."schema_migrations"' in the cache. Attempting to load the tablespace with space id 4.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 127a27000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4959924224 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for 'or_deco__site_development/schema_migrations'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html for how to resolve the issue.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.32-79.0 started; log sequence number 2135725
2017-06-07 18:10:55 4961533952 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Address already in use
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /tmp/mysql.sock ?
2017-06-07 18:10:55 140735296021248 [ERROR] Aborting
```

What should I do to fix this ?

EDIT

After looking around, I tried numerous things:

1) I tried to stop all mysql running processes
I still have one process that I cant kill because the pid is constantly changing

```
ps aux |grep mysql

davidgeismar    19342   0.0  0.0  2432772    532 s000  R+    7:00PM   0:00.00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn mysql
```

2) I also tried creating the mysql.sock file in /tmp as my original error message was :     `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61 "Connection refused")`
without more success

3) I tried desinstalling and reinstalling mysql via homebrew several times

4) I also checked the rights on `cd /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18_1/` and Im getting this :

```
-rw-r--r--   1 _mysql  _mysql  17987 Mar 18 08:56 COPYING
-rw-r--r--   1 _mysql  _mysql   1234 Jun  9 18:27 INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
-rw-r--r--   1 _mysql  _mysql   2478 Mar 18 08:56 README
drwxr-xr-x  42 _mysql  _mysql   1428 Jun  9 18:27 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 _mysql  _mysql     68 Jun  9 18:51 data
-rw-r--r--   1 _mysql  _mysql    543 Jun  9 18:27 homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
drwxr-xr-x   3 _mysql  _mysql    102 Mar 18 08:56 include
drwxr-xr-x   9 _mysql  _mysql    306 Mar 18 08:56 lib
drwxr-xr-x   3 _mysql  _mysql    102 Mar 18 08:56 scripts
drwxr-xr-x   6 _mysql  _mysql    204 Mar 18 08:56 share
drwxr-xr-x   6 _mysql  _mysql    204 Jun  9 18:27 support-files
```

everything seems to be owned by mysql which is supposed to be the correct permissions from what I read...

I really dont know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

You should supply the *password of the DB* in the `database.yml` file that is associated with the *username root*

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: root
  password: Your_DB_Password_Here
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: or_deco__site_development
```

***Update:***

You should *set password to a root user* and use that in `database.yml`. Try the below to set the password.

```
$ mysql -u root -p

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = 'your_password_here'
```

Comment: I understand, but I didnt define any password for the DB

Comment: @DavidGeismar Are you sure? While install mysql it will ask to set a password for root. Did you set empty?

Comment: i didnt set any password

Comment: I tried this but after $ mysql -u root -p, I m getting ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (61 "Connection refused")

Comment: @DavidGeismar Try removing `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock` from the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146091/discussion-between-david-geismar-and-pavan).

Comment: @DavidGeismar Did removing `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock` solved the error?